# Como fechar a Form em que estou?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

```
private void BtnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string login = txtLogin.Text;
        Conta conta = new Conta();
        try
        {
            BLL bll = new BLL();
            conta = bll.SelectContaByLogin(login);
            if(txtSenha.Text == conta.Senha)
            {
                TelaDeLogin form1 = new TelaDeLogin();
                form1.Close();
                TelaInicial form2 = new TelaInicial();
                form2.ShowDialog();

            } else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login ou senha incorretos.");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Estou fazendo um sistema de Login e Senha no Visual Studio com C#, e preciso fechar a `form` de Login quando o usuário entrar.

A parte de abrir a `form` da Tela Inicial funciona, mas o `form1.Close()` não funciona. Tentei `Hide()`, tentei `this.Close()`, mas também não está fechando.

Comment: `this.Hide()` não funciona?

Comment: Faça-me um favor. Se nenhuma das resposta á baixo resolver seu problema publique o código do evento `onClose` do formulário `TelaDeLogin` .

Answer (score 1):

Ele não fecha devido ao  `ShowDialog()`

```
private void BtnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string login = txtLogin.Text;
    Conta conta = new Conta();
    try
    {
        BLL bll = new BLL();
        conta = bll.SelectContaByLogin(login);
        if(txtSenha.Text == conta.Senha)
        {
            this.Hide();
            TelaInicial form2 = new TelaInicial();
            form2.Show();

        } else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login ou senha incorretos.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Feche com:

```
form1.Dispose();
```

Isto irá encerrar a instância de vez.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço assim e funciona de boa:

```
Hide(); 
using (var homeScreen = new MdlHomeScreen())
{
  homeScreen.Closed += (s, args) => Close();
  homeScreen.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Forma mais rápida:

```
Application.OpenForms[1].Close();
```

O número dentro do dos colchetes é o form que deseja fechar...

Comment: Isso não fecha a `Form` aberta. Se tiver mais de um `Form` aberto, poderá fechar a errada. E se tiver apenas uma, um `IndexOutOfRangeException` será causado.

Comment: Seria melhor passa o parâmetro `Form.Name` ao inés de um índice numérico.